# How to order by column minus first character in a select distinct statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to organize a query based on a column in sequential order in a select distinct statement. The select distinct statement concatenates a character onto the front of a number (i.e "S1", "S2"..."S11") .

Here is the code:

```
    select distinct 
        s.book_Id as EpbookId
        ,concat('S',ps.Param_Value) as bookID
        ,concat(sa.Location,'-',s.book_Number) as Label
        ,concat('<book ID="',concat('S',ps.Param_Value),
            '" label="',concat(sa.Location,'-',s.book_Number),'"/>') as DataLine
        from 
            books s
            inner join books_Address sa on 
                s.book_Id = sa.book_Id 
                and sa.Addr_Type_Id = 1
                and s.bookS_TYPE_ID = 1
                and s.Active = 1
            inner join Parameters_books ps on 
                ps.book_Id = s.book_Id
                and ps.Param_Id = @bookParam
```

1. Essentially I just need to order by `ps.Param_Value`
2. The problem is I can't use a simple `ORDER BY ps.Param_Value`
   because I do not have `ps.Param_Value` in my select distinct statement.
3. I also can not order by `bookID` because the result is not ordered
   correctly due to the letter in the front.
4. I also tried ordering by `SUBSTRING(bookID, 1, 10)` but again unless I put `SUBSTRING(bookID, 1, 10)` in my select statement it will not work Due to it being a select distinct statement.

So is there a way to order by the numbers that follow the concatenated 'S' without adding something extra to my select statement. OR is it possible to add `ps.Param_Value` to my select distinct statement without it actually coming back in my data?

Comment: `order by concat('S',ps.param_value)` will work.

Comment: @Hellion unfortunately when I  order by concat('S',ps.param_value), I get "S1","S10","S11","S12"..."S2","S3". Because it no longer recognizes multi-digit numbers.

Comment: Which table is creating the non-distinct rows in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I 100% follow, but I believe you could just:

- keep the ps.param_value in the distinct
- Add a select around the distinct block that computes the S + concat logic
- put an order by ps.param_value in the outer select

(you may want to explicitly list all columns, but I've omitted them for brevity here)

```
SELECT 
*, 
concat('S',ps.Param_Value) as bookID
FROM
(
  select distinct 
        s.book_Id as EpbookId
        ,ps.Param_Value as Param_Value
        ,concat(sa.Location,'-',s.book_Number) as Label
        ,concat('<book ID="',concat('S',ps.Param_Value),
            '" label="',concat(sa.Location,'-',s.book_Number),'"/>') as DataLine
        from 
            books s
            inner join books_Address sa on 
                s.book_Id = sa.book_Id 
                and sa.Addr_Type_Id = 1
                and s.bookS_TYPE_ID = 1
                and s.Active = 1
            inner join Parameters_books ps on 
                ps.book_Id = s.book_Id
                and ps.Param_Id = @bookPara
) A
ORDER BY
Param_Value
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer here Conor. Could you show me what this would like I think you follow what I am wanting and are on the right track. I am just not sure how this would look. Also do you know if this would hurt the speed of the query by nesting select statements?

Comment: No, adding a nested block has no substantial impact on query performance in general.  It is far, far less of an issue than doing joins or distinct wrt performance impact (which also may not be problems in this case - hard to tell without sample data sets and such)

Comment: As an optimization do you think it would benefit the query for the inner `distinct` to operate only on the straight column values, waiting to concatenate them all at a higher level?

Comment: potentially it would help but I don't have a strong opinion about how much it would help.  If you can isolate presentation logic stuff to the top, it usually does help the QP do things more easily/potentially optimize more.  I would view this from a design standpoint of the app more than strictly trying to make the query go faster, myself.

Answer (score 1):

For your particular example, you can use

```
order by DataLine
```

The `ps.Param_Value` value is first non-constant element of the string, so this should do what you want.

The more generic solution is to use `group by` and then use `order by min(ps.Param_Value)`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Gordon! When I order by DataLine  it returns "S1","S10","S11","S12"..."S2","S3", I think this is because it no longer recognizes multi-digit numbers. Could you elaborate on your second suggestion of using group by and order by min(ps.Param_Value). What would I want to by? Would I still need to have min(ps.Param_Value) be apart of my select statment?

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct 
EpbookId,CONCAT('S',bookID) AS bookId, Label, DataLine
from
(SELECT 
        s.book_Id as EpbookId
        ,ps.Param_Value as bookID
        ,concat(sa.Location,'-',s.book_Number) as Label
        ,concat('<book ID="',concat('S',ps.Param_Value),
            '" label="',concat(sa.Location,'-',s.book_Number),'"/>') as DataLine
        from 
            books s
            inner join books_Address sa on 
                s.book_Id = sa.book_Id 
                and sa.Addr_Type_Id = 1
                and s.bookS_TYPE_ID = 1
                and s.Active = 1
            inner join Parameters_books ps on 
                ps.book_Id = s.book_Id
                and ps.Param_Id = @bookParam
                ORDER BY ps.param_value
                ) myTempView
```